# Oracle Database 10g JRE Error

Tags: oracle-10g, java

I am trying to install Oracle Database 10.2 on OEL5U6(Linux System). I followed all the instructions from [HERE.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-db-10gr2-installation-on-rhel-4.php)
When I am executing installer this return:

> Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from
>   /tmp/OraInstall2013-08-06_12-57-33AM. Please wait ...The Java RunTime
>   Environment was not found at
>   /tmp/OraInstall2013-08-06_12-57-33AM/jre/bin/java. Hence, the Oracle
>   Universal Installer cannot be run. Please visit
>   http://www.javasoft.com and install JRE version 1.3.1 or higher and
>   try again. : No such file or directory.

But Java is already installed on my system.

Answer (score -2):

Please Do the below written instructions:

1. Set the class path of latest version of Java in your system  .
2. set the path as JAVA_HOME in Environment variable too.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: so could you plz tell me how to get the location of class path and JAVA_HOME location, sp that I can set these two above.

Comment: Go to the properties of your computer with right click on it.Now click on the advanced option shown last on the top left side.Now go to environment variables under system variables,click on new and set your classpath.

Comment: Is your system linux or windows???

Comment: and the location of the programs are under the java and oracle database folders in the program files.

Comment: @Ritzz081: he/she mentioned "OEL5u6" in the original question. I guess that's "Oracle Enterprise Linux"

Comment: Java   ==  program files -> Java -> Jre -> copy the address bar and paste it in path.

oracle  == program files  -> oracle database  -> JAVA_HOME  ->copy the address bar and paste it in path

Comment: its Oracle Enterprise Linux.

Comment: Not a big deal.Just follow the same as in linux

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html
 you can use this link too

Comment: You're all looking at the wrong thing. The Oracle installer comes with a bundled JRE, which gets copied to `/tmp`. The most likely scenario is that `/tmp` was full when the installer tried to copy the JRE there. Look in the log file generated by the installer to see what the real error is.